# Is is possible to send files from smartphone to a PC via USB (Export commanded from the smartphone)?

Tags: usb, file-transfer

I have files (mainly pictures) selected under android file manager or photo viewer.
Is it possible to send them to a PC via an USB connection ?

My aim is to do the file selection on the android device, and export this selection of files from the android device to the PC.

I know how to connect the PC via USB to the android device, and to  copy using the PC file manager. However with this procedure I have to retrieve the file from the PC on the memory of the android device, which I would like to avoid (because it's time consuming and prone to errors)

*(Running Android >=9, PC with Linux OS)*

Best Regards

Comment: no, there exist no method to send files to PC

Comment: If the PC is running Linux, set-up an SSH server on it and copy the files via an SCP capable file-manager or Termux SCP command-line/script.